# Real estate property listing formatting

Tags: website-design, icon, interface-design

Working on this real estate development website with multiple units for sale, each of these listing the number of bedrooms, bathrooms, floor and unit surface per unit (below the 'Family Unit' title).

I am trying to avoid using more explicit icons like a bed, a toilet, stairs, etc and the client is fine with using bullet type the-same-for-everything kind of icon. The trouble is I'm not sure this bulleted arrow I am currently using is the best way to list these.

What other options do I have?

[image]

Comment: A little cross, like a plus symbol? Or a little dash, like a minus symbol?

Comment: But _why_ are you "trying to avoid using more explicit icons like a bed, a toilet, stairs, etc". They might be boring, but to my mind they convey the information in the most efficient, expected and user-friendly manner. Just maybe try and find/create some nice ones! Certainly you could create some minimalistic ones and put them in the circle for example.

Comment: I thought about that, but there many units in a grid and will prefer to not increase the size of the space allowed for these specs, and having explicit icons so tiny may not work. I actually tried that but didn't particulary like it, was looking for a more minimal way to showcase this, like a horizontal bullet list, which it is, i just don't like the bullets :)

Comment: You have an infinite amount of options, which makes this question too broad to be answered objectively.

Comment: Definitely broad and opinion based, was just thinking maybe i'm missing some very obvious solution here. The website itself is quite minimal and doesn't particularly follow the usual real estate website 'recipe'.

Comment: I agree with @mayersdesign I think you totally should use explicit icons showing what exactly it is.

Comment: *Avoiding* instantly identifiable, common, industry-wide, icons merely means you **introduce** a level of confusion and add a learning curve to *this* specific site. Not a great choice in my opinion. Use standard icons, even small 12/16px black only icons are better. A toilet icon is never mistaken for a bed icon regardless of their sizes.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use recognisable icons so the user immediately recognises the information, and can also associate it with the same information on multiple listings.

Answer (score 1):

See now me, I would've done a "standard" symbology wrapped into a black circle to keep your figure-ground consistency.

Then again, this kind of thing is very specifically up my alley anyway - architectural illustration / graphics.

Something perhaps along this direction, but better developed (this was ~ 4 minutes) and more carefully matched to the website content:

[image]